# Dynamic Web App to Phonegap

Tags: html, node.js, cordova

I'm trying to turn a simple webapp into an Android app by using Phonegap Build. My webapp has some simple jQuery AJAX methods (GET/POST). I'm not sure how to go about this -- when I upload the zip to Phonegap Build, the zip includes the html file, the css file, and a js script which is basically the Node.js server.

My HTML file includes some javascript that relies on GET/POST from the server, but it never runs in the android app that is built. I have tried whitelisting the localhost in the config.xml file (10.0.2.2) but this is also not working. Anyone have an idea? Should I not be using Phonegap Build? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap will not allow you to run any node.js script. Node.js - is server side solution.

What you are looking for is to make front-end in html+css+js, that will speak to your node.js using AJAX. But node.js have to run on hosting that will be available online. So that way your application will speak to node.js process that will server all clients (PhoneGap applications) via HTTP (AJAX).

Please remember, that StackOverflow helps with specific code problem, not knowledge or generic questions.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. To clarify, running the node.js on localhost won't work because the PhoneGap applications won't be able to access it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can run it on localhost, but then you have to make sure that you have your testing device within same wifi/localarea connection, and you can connect to your node using local IP of computer that runs node.js process.
In order to test online - you will have to have static IP or Hosting that will have IP and will allow you to run node.js.